# Share event function into other component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a react project 'til I can't pursue because of share event function into other componant.

I share you 3 react code :

AppBarPhone.jsx : contains the first function `handleAddPaymentClick`,

App.jsx : contains all views

Home.jsx : contains the main view, and there is the point, because I can't pass `handleAddPaymentClick` function from AppBarPhone.jsx into Home.jsx by passing by App.jsx

AppBarPhone.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react'; import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'; import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add'; import Fab from '@mui/material/Fab';

export default function BottomAppBar({ logout, children, onClickAddPaymentCallback }) {
    const handleAddPaymentClick = (result) => {
        if (onClickAddPaymentCallback) {
            onClickAddPaymentCallback(result);
        }
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        // other code
                    <StyledFab onClick={handleAddPaymentClick} aria-label="add">
                        <AddIcon />
                    </StyledFab>
                    // other code
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    // I want to have event here when button from AppBarPhone is clicked

    render() {
        return (
            // code
        );
    };
};
export default Home;
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './views/Home';
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';
import AppBarPhone from './components/AppBarPhone';
import cookiesManager from './utils/CookiesManager';
import Redirector from './utils/Redirector';
import { Routing } from './utils/Routing';
import Login from './views/Auth/Login';
import Utils from './utils/Utils';
import './views/css/main.css';

class App extends Component {
  handleAddPaymentClick = (event) => {
    this.handleAddPaymentClickCallBack = (onResponse) => {
      onResponse(event);
    };
  };


  render() {
    if (cookiesManager.getCookie('logged_in') === 'True') {
      if (window.location.pathname === "/")
        Redirector.redirect(Routing.main.HOME);
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          {Utils.isOnPhone() ?
            <AppBarPhone
              logout={this.logout}
              onClickAddPaymentCallback={this.handleAddPaymentClick}
              children={
                <Routes>
                  <Route exact path={Routing.main.HOME} element={
                    <Home
                      onClickAddPayment={this.handleAddPaymentClickCallBack} // click function
                      getPayment={this.get_payment}
                      addPayment={this.add_payment}
                      validePaiementEmetteur={this.valide_paiement_emetteur}
                      validePaiementDestinataire={this.valide_paiement_destinataire}
                      findUser={this.find_user}
                    />
                  } />
                </Routes>}
            />
            : <AppBar
              logout={this.logout}
              children={
                <Routes>
                  {/* <Route exact path={Routing.ALL} element={<Oops />} /> */}
                  <Route exact path={Routing.main.HOME} element={
                    <Home
                      getPayment={this.get_payment}
                      addPayment={this.add_payment}
                      validePaiementEmetteur={this.valide_paiement_emetteur}
                      validePaiementDestinataire={this.valide_paiement_destinataire}
                      findUser={this.find_user}
                    />
                  } />
                </Routes>} />}
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path={Routing.all.ALL} element={<Login auth={this.authentification} />} />
            {/* <Route exact path={Routing.REGI} element={<Register regi={this.signup} />} /> */}
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    };
  };
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand your issue. What's the issue ? What did you try for resolving it ?

Comment: I have a function handleAddPaymentClick in AppBarPhone.jsx, the AppBar is imported in App.jsx where Home.jsx is also imported so I just want to have the result of the handleAddPaymentClick function in my Home view